# How can I view data usage on my home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My ISP has a 1TB cap on my usage and we nearly hit that cap or go over each month. I want to be able to see some data on this so I can see what is using the data and what the device/network is calling so much to use all that data. I know this is a complex question but been searching all over. I know I may need a new router to do so but want to be sure I am going in the right direction. I asked them for the usage and they told me it's private and cannot supply it.

Ideally I would like to see which services/domains and how much bytes they are using, but at a minimum see how much each device is using.

Currently Set-Up:
Motorola Arris Surfboard (2014)
Apple Airport Extrene (2013 maybe)

Comment: They told you the usage information is private, yet they're billing you based on this "secret" information???